# Birt 4.4.1 : Export to pdf does not display an image

Tags: ckeditor, pdf-generation, birt, rich-text-editor

My birt edition contains a picture, when I export to HTML, the image is displayed by against export in pdf does not work and the following message appears "The resource of this deferred item is not reachable . "

I consulted your forum but I have not found a clear solution on this, below the simplified rptdesign problem file,

knowing that it was me who suggested to my team worked with Birt based on my three years of experience of birt :3 , I am afraid that the example below will not display properly in pdf which means that I have to look for other tools (or library) that will allow me to display the contents of TextEditor in the generated pdf. :(

just for information:

- content to be displayed is retrieved from the database (which stores the contents of a TextEditor).
- Birt version used is 4.4.1

file : [export_to_pdf.rptdesign](https://app.box.com/s/mg2hmn0cls3zdl93mykczlf9odwvv22q)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: We can display a dynamic image in a report using the "image" birt element, and this one would be correctly exported in PDF. However in your sample the image is a string base64 encoded, embedded in a HTML text. If i correctly understood the use case, your whole report will mainly be a single HTML text element? AFAIK, the PDF emitter can't handle this kind of image natively. It could probably be extended to support this though.

Comment: @Dominique :  The above example is just a simplification of the problem I have, but my final edition contains SEVERAL table & graph.
So from what I understand, BIRT can not manage an html content that contains a formatted image base64 encoded :(, and the big problem for me is that the rich-TextEditor (eg: ckeditor) typically generate text in html format and this is what I saved in the database and I have no other trick to solve this problem !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the response of "[JFreeman](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/35921-export-to-pdf-does-not-display-an-image/)" I think what I want is not currently possible because the image I want to display is encapsulated within the HTML tags,

> The reason the image does not display in PDF is due to being in an HTML text element using HTML to convert the base64 into the image. This HTML code will be executed client side within the browser and does not occur when the report is exported to PDF which is generated server side.

but I managed to get around this by using the following method:

- I created a java process that extracts the code64 image encapsulated
  within HTML tags, I run the physical creation of the image, and I
  store it in a previously created folder in my server .
- This treatment java provided me complete URL of the picture created
  this url will be stored in a new table called "illustration"
- I replace the code64 from the image with the text **(see illustration NamedOrnumber541 in the appendix section)**, the new channel created will be stored in a new column, and the content of the new column will appear in the edition birt .
- At the end of the generated report, I display all images related to the edition launched with components "Image" parameterized "Image file in shared resources," and the URL of the image to display is stored on in the illustration table as previously reported.
- And by the end, in my database, I have two columns, the first contains the base64 encoded image encapsulated within HTML tags (content TextEditor) and the second column will contain the same content the first column except that instead of having the code64 image I have just indicating that the image to see is in the last part of the report (Annex) that displays images already generated by my java treatment.

it is true that this algorithm is a bit complex (I will do a small project that will contain all the treatment / control done once I have time) but the key is how to convince the customer that this solution is desirable for clear visibility of the text entered by users and not be bothered by the pictures :-).

Comment: Hi Nimpo, have you created a small project to represent your solution?

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the base64 image for PDF as well, you can use a dynamic image element with scripting in the onCreate of the image element to decode the base64.

```
importPackage(Packages.javax.imageio);
importPackage(Packages.java.io);
importPackage(Packages.sun.misc);
decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(this.getRowData().getColumnValue("CLOBData"));
this.data =decodedBytes;
bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( decodedBytes);
bufimg = ImageIO.read(bais);
this.setHeight(bufimg.getHeight() +"px");
this.setWidth(bufimg.getWidth() +"px");
```

from: http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/35862-dynamic-textclob-dataset-html-content-not-showing-the-html-embeded-image-base64/

Alternative

```
<value-of format="HTML"> if(row["B_CONTENT"] == null) {"";}else{ "<img src='data:image/png;base64,"}</value-of><value-of format="HTML"> row["B_CONTENT"]</value-of><value-of format="HTML"> if(row["B_CONTENT"] == null ) {"";}else{"' height='120' width='100' />"} </value-of>
```

from: http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/29367-print-image-base64-in-birt-report/

Comment: your solution works only if the content I have is just a coding image code64, but my example is a code64 image encapsulated within HTML tags :(

Comment: I found a workaround  (not technical) but I have no right to post a reply, my account is currently banned, I will post it as a comment but you will lose the formatting of the text and it will be misread,
hoping that my contribution on this forum will help me to get out of the black list site :)